# PL/SQL script to search for a particular string in data from the entire database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I work on Oracle SQL Developer and looking for a script for which the input will be -
$1 - String to be searched
$2 - String to be replaced with
The script will find for $1 in all TABLE/VIEWS/FUNCTIONS/PACKAGES, etc. and will replace with $2 from the entire database of a particular schema.
The output should be the count of replacements.

Guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot mass update code like this. Run such a replacement in your master code/object files (e.g. from source control) outside the database and then compile the updated files against the database. And code changes are entirely different than data changes in tables. That also should not be universalized like this.

Comment: You mean I need to export the complete data outside of database and then run replacement logic which is not my use-case.

Comment: Not data, code. Views/functions/packages/procedures/triggers are code. If you want to update *data* in tables that's an entirely different thing. It can be scripted but is generally a bad idea to do this universally across the database - too easy to mess up and lose data.

Comment: Yes so I need to modify data inside Tables/Views/Functions/packages, etc. and for that I'm looking for any PL/SQL block with minimal lines

Comment: you keep speaking of Tables together with Views/Functions/Packages. Tables are completely different things - they store data, whereas everything else you are mentioning is programming code, not data. How they work and how you change these two (data vs. code) are entirely different and don't belong even in the same discussion. If you want some guidance, you'll need to clarify exactly what needs to be changed and in what ways it needs to be changed.

Comment: Ok got it, changing my words.. I need Tables data to be searched for a specific string and if found would need to replace with another string. I got your point Views Package,etc. does not have data inside them is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the table data containing certain string in any column then it could be done using dynamic sql and pl/sql. It is quite risky action, though. You realy should at least be sure to target tables to those that such an action would not compromise accidentaly. Here is a rough sample of an option to do it (with some test data).
TEST Tables:

```sql
Create Table TEST_TBL_1 (ID Number(6), TEXT_1 VarChar2(16), A_DATE DATE, TEXT_2 VarChar2(16));
Insert Into TEST_TBL_1
  ( Select 11, 'abcdef', DATE '2024-01-01', '***XYZ***' From Dual Union All
    Select 12, 'ghijkl', DATE '2024-01-02', Null From Dual Union All
    Select 13, 'mnopqr', DATE '2024-01-03', '***XYZ***' From Dual 
  );
Create Table TEST_TBL_2 (ID Number(6), STR_1 VarChar2(16));
Insert Into TEST_TBL_2
  ( Select 21, 'tbl_2_A' From Dual Union All
    Select 22, 'tbl_2_B' From Dual Union All
    Select 23, 'tbl_2_C' From Dual 
  );
Create Table TEST_TBL_3 (ID Number(6), TXT VarChar2(16));
Insert Into TEST_TBL_3
  ( Select 31, '***XYZ***' From Dual Union All
    Select 32, '***XYZ***' From Dual Union All
    Select 33, Null From Dual 
  );
```

PL/SQL Block

```sql
Set SERVEROUTPUT ON
--
-- replacing '***XYZ***' with '==>xyz<=='
--
Declare
    Cursor c Is
          Select  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
          From    all_tab_columns 
          Where   OWNER = 'YOUR_OWNER_NAME' And 
                  TABLE_NAME Like 'TEST_TBL_%' And  -- limiting to just TEST Tables
                  DATA_TYPE = 'VARCHAR2';
    mTab  VarChar2(32);
    mCol  VarChar2(32);
    mCmd  VarChar2(255);
    mCnt  Number(6) := 0;
    mTotal  Number(6) := 0;
    --
    strToReplace  VarChar2(12) := '***XYZ***';
    strReplacement  VarChar2(12) := '==>xyz<==';
Begin
    Open c;
    Loop
        Fetch c Into mTab, mCol;
        Exit When c%NOTFOUND;
        mCmd := 'Select Count(*) From ' || mTab || ' Where InStr(' || mCol || ', ''' || strToReplace || ''') > 0';
        Execute Immediate mCmd Into mCnt;
        If mCnt > 0 Then
            mCmd := 'Update ' || mTab || Chr(10) || 
                    'Set ' || mCol || ' = Replace(' || mCol || ', ''' || strToReplace || ''', ''' || strReplacement || ''') ' || Chr(10) ||
                    'Where InStr(' || mCol || ', ''' || strToReplace || ''') > 0';
            Execute Immediate mCmd;
            Commit;
            mTotal := mTotal + mCnt;
        End If;
    End Loop;
    Close c;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mTotal || ' rows updated');
End;
```

```sql
--       R e s u l t :
--  4 rows updated
--  PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

TEST Tables - Before and After

```sql
Select * From TEST_TBL_1;
/*   B e f o r e :
        ID TEXT_1           A_DATE   TEXT_2          
---------- ---------------- -------- ----------------
        11 abcdef           01.01.24 ***XYZ***       
        12 ghijkl           02.01.24                 
        13 mnopqr           03.01.24 ***XYZ***          */
/*   A f t e r :
        ID TEXT_1           A_DATE   TEXT_2          
---------- ---------------- -------- ----------------
         1 abcdef           01.01.24 ==>xyz<==       
         1 ghijkl           02.01.24                 
         1 mnopqr           03.01.24 ==>xyz<==          */
         
Select * From TEST_TBL_2;
/*   B e f o r e    &   A f t e r :
        ID STR_1           
---------- ----------------
        21 tbl_2_A         
        22 tbl_2_B         
        23 tbl_2_C             */

Select * From TEST_TBL_3;
/*   B e f o r e :
        ID TXT             
---------- ----------------
        31 ***XYZ***       
        32 ***XYZ***       
        33                    */
/*   A f t e r :
        ID TXT             
---------- ----------------
        31 ==>xyz<==       
        32 ==>xyz<==       
        33                    */
```

Comment: Thanks, this is somewhat I was looking for. I'll update once I'll thoroughly test it for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible directly. So like Paul W said, you should do this outside the database.
What you can do however is export your source easily into files with following select (only for function and procedure, but you can extend it for other objects) you will get your data extracted and you can put it into files:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type,object_name,owner) 
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('FUNCTION,'PROCEDURE);
```

After this you can change the string in the files. And then compile all the objects back against the database. Then everything will be changed.